# How to make php work on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new to php and wordpress. I use a plugin called `“PHP Execution”` to make my php code run on wordpress. But when I put my php code in word press and press a button to calculate, it shows an error page `(404 — Fancy meeting you here!)` and doesn't show the results of my code.

Following is the code I posted on wordpress page:

```
<?php
isset($_POST['name']) ? $name = $_POST['name'] : $name = "empty";
isset($_POST['age']) ? $age = $_POST['age'] : $age = 0;
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

Enter the name:<input type="text" size="12" size="50" name="name"><br />
Enter the age:      <input type="text" size="12" size="90" name="age"><br />
<input type="submit" value="Pin It" name="submit">

</form>

<?php
echo "the name: " . $name . "<br />";
echo "the age: ", $age;
?>
```

Result:
[image]

---

**After putting values in the name field and age field, 
pressing `"Pin It"` button:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to use eval()?

Comment: review this... http://wordpress.org/support/topic/404-error-when-previewing-a-post

Comment: reinstall wordpress 3.5... check out this link ...http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update

Comment: @thumbernirmal Thank you for the link. but the instructions was little hard to follow. is it telling me to get a theme called twenty twelve? when I search for the theme, it says it's already installed. So, I deleted it and active the team `Twenty Twelve`, but the result is still the same. Can you please tell me what steps I should follow? And do I have to do anything with permalink to make this work? I really apriciate your help.

Comment: @thumbernirmal I have done a manual update as you instructed in the second link. Still the same result and luck

Comment: It is always advisable not to include PHP code into page/post. Instead write it into theme's index.php or functions.php.
Also you could consider encapsulating the code in a plugin.

Comment: Something is wrong with `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not the best idea to use PHP code directly in the Post Entry fields. Instead you could do the following:

Duplicate page.php and rename it into page-custom.php

Open page-custom.php and replace this:

```
 * The template for displaying all pages.
```

With the following:

```
* Template Name: Custom Template Justin
```

You just made a custom template. You can enter your PHP code in the page-custom.php that you would like to see displayed later.

Now... when you are creating or editing a page from the Wordpress admin, on the right side you will see the option **Template**, select *Custom Template Justin* from the dropdown and view your page.

Your PHP code should be executed there.